# Webcam App in Java

Tags: java, video, webcam

I want to make a webcam app that runs off Jymron but I don't really know how to install it so I can use it in my program. I tried copying the Jmyron.jar into build path but it wouldn't work. The HowToInstall.txt says "Copy the 'JMyron' folder found in this directory into the Processing/libraries directory". I'm very confused can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know that when I put an external Jar into my project I do this. Im not sure if this will work for you.

> File -> New -> Java Project -> (Type in Name) -> Next -> Libraries (One of the tabs)

Then use that to add the library. If it is a Jar use Add External JAR